# Scipy multidimensional kernel density estimate

Tags: python, scipy

I've been trying to get a kernal density estimate for a 30x30 array. A short example is below,

```
from scipy.stats import gaussian_kde

x = arange(-0.5,0.51,1/29.)
y = arange(-0.5,0.51,1/29.)
z = randn(30,30)

vec = vstack((x,y))

KDE = gaussian_kde(z.T)
KDE2 = KDE(vec)
```

this gives the following error,

```
ValueError: points have dimension 2, dataset has dimension 30
```

I've found some other posts here which suggest the data needs to be reshaped before the estimate but I am unsure how to do this correctly.

Any help appreciated
D

Comment: Could you please provide these posts with the suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

with `KDE = gaussian_kde(z.T)` you are making a kernel density estimation of `30` random variables (check `KDE.n`), each of the variable with `30` dimensions (check `KDE.d`).

If you are studying some data, that data is the input to `gaussian_kde()`.

With `KDE(vec)` you then estimate the kernel density of `z`. The input must have shape `(30,)` or `(30,N)` where `30` is the number of dimensions `KDE.d`. See the doc [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gaussian_kde.evaluate.html).

It doesn't make any sense to feed `x,y` with those shapes. The example [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gaussian_kde.html) should get you started. In that example, `d=2` and `n= 2000`.